# how to reset particular variable value after 1 day in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

How can I reset the variable after one day? I have used this code but this code removes the values from the overall app, not from the particular variable.
How can we reset particular variable after one day with `UserDefaults` and without `UserDefaults`?

```
extension UserDefaults {

    static let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    static var lastAccessDate: Date? {
        get {
            return defaults.object(forKey: "lastAccessDate") as? Date
        }
        set {
            guard let newValue = newValue else { return }
            guard let lastAccessDate = lastAccessDate else {
                defaults.set(newValue, forKey: "lastAccessDate")
                return
            }
            if !Calendar.current.isDateInToday(lastAccessDate) {
                print("remove Persistent Domain")
                UserDefaults.reset()
            }
            defaults.set(newValue, forKey: "lastAccessDate")
        }
    }

    static func reset() {
        defaults.removePersistentDomain(forName: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "")
    }
}
```

Comment: `defaults.removeObject(forKey: "keyYouWantToRemove")` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your reset function removes all UserDefaults associated with you app.

To remove a particular key use this:

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "lastAccessDate")
```

Comment: Can you tell me the structure. how can i link it with 1 day

Comment: for example i have 6 keys of userdefaults. then how can i write to set those with day and how to fetch that

Comment: PLease provide a example with removing one value after one day

Comment: @UmairAhmad don't call reset() instead call the function I put above